# Masked MovieClip area is included in height

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml, flash-cs6

- I have a `MovieClip` which I compiled to SWC and imported to Flash Builder.
- The `MovieClip` has a masked (visible) area, and an invisible area which is hidden by the mask:

  [image: MC]
- I wrapped the MC in a `UIMovieClip` so that I could insert in the MXML of the application:

  `<my:SomeMaskedControl bottom="0" />`
- In the MXML I set the attribute `bottom="0"`, I wanted the `UIMovieClip` to sit at the bottom of the application. Unfortunately the invisible area of the MC is messing it up:

  [image: Application]
- I wanted it more like this:

  [image: BetterApplication]

I realize that I could just change the `bottom` attribute to a negative value, but I think this would mess up the architecture of the application. Is there a way to fix it so that I can still use `bottom="0"`?

Comment: I think it is because it is a MovieClip what if you exported as a swf instead of swc, maybe that might work?

Comment: You may need to override the height property of that MovieClip and return the height from an intersection of the masked object's bounds with the bounds of the mask.

Comment: try bottom for mask=0 and top of movieclip="{mask.x}"

Comment: bottom = mask.height-this.height or possible you will need to call updateDisplayList

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Colin Moock hack : http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000292.html

```
public class SomeMaskedControl extends UIMovieClip
{
    protected var mc:MaskedMC;

    public function SomeMaskedControl()
    {
        super();

        mc = new MaskedMC();

        addChild(mc);
    }

    public function getVisibleHeight (o:DisplayObject):Number {
        var bitmapDataSize:int = 2000;
        var bounds:Rectangle;
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bitmapDataSize, bitmapDataSize, true, 0);
        bitmapData.draw(o);
        bounds = bitmapData.getColorBoundsRect( 0xFF000000, 0x00000000, false );
        bitmapData.dispose(); 
        return bounds.y + bounds.height;
    }

    override public function get height():Number
    {
        return getVisibleHeight( mc );
    }
}
```

But i don't like this way. If you will can create mask as MovieClip, and set instance name, in application you can get mask.height and replace UIMovieClip height:

```
public class SomeMaskedControl extends UIMovieClip
{
    protected var mc:MaskedMC;

    public function SomeMaskedControl()
    {
        super();

        mc = new MaskedMC();

        addChild(mc);
    }

    override public function get height():Number
    {
        return mc.maskMC.height;
    }
}
```